# Angular Summernote text wrapped in <p> tag

Tags: angularjs, summernote

I have an angular application where [angular summernote texteditor](https://github.com/summernote/angular-summernote) is added in  header text. It is working but my problem is when I am adding the header text, it is wrapped with a `<p></p>` tag. and when I display it on preview page,  `<p></p>` tag is also exist there.

How can I remove html tags when saving data to JSON file?

Comment: In this demo that does not happen if you use style button - http://jsfiddle.net/outsider/n8dt4/322/embedded/result%2Chtml%2Cjs%2Ccss/